# Why is the #reset button executing the Flow.reset() function even if #gameboard has no children elements?

Tags: javascript

When i click on resetBtn it always executes Flow.reset function, no matter if gameboard has children elements or not, am i using the hasChildNodes() incorrectly?

```
const resetBtn = document.querySelector('#reset');
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (document.getElementById('gameboard').hasChildNodes()) {
    Flow.reset();
   } 
  else {
    return;
  }
});
```

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainContainer">
        <h1 class="header">Tic Tac Toe</h1>
        <div class="gameBoard" id="gameboard">

        </div>
        <div class="names-container">
            <input type="text" id="player1" placeholder="Player 1 Name">
            <input type="text" id="player2" placeholder="Player 2 Name">
        </div>
        <div class="buttonsContainer">
            <button class="startBtn" id="start" class="name-field">Start</button>
            <button class="resetBtn" id="reset" class="name-field">Reset</button>
        </div>
        <div class="message"></div>
        <div class="resultsContainer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the HTML for the game board look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is the problem, by putting an extra line into the div, you provide a childNode.

The following returns true, because there is content between the `<div>` tags.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('gameboard').hasChildNodes())
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
    <h1 class="header">Tic Tac Toe</h1>
    <div class="gameBoard" id="gameboard">

    </div>
    <div class="names-container">
        <input type="text" id="player1" placeholder="Player 1 Name">
        <input type="text" id="player2" placeholder="Player 2 Name">
    </div>
    <div class="buttonsContainer">
        <button class="startBtn" id="start" class="name-field">Start</button>
        <button class="resetBtn" id="reset" class="name-field">Reset</button>
    </div>
    <div class="message"></div>
    <div class="resultsContainer"></div>
</div>
```

If you remove the whitespace between the tags, it returns false, and works as you expect.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('gameboard').hasChildNodes())
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
    <h1 class="header">Tic Tac Toe</h1>
    <div class="gameBoard" id="gameboard"></div>
    <div class="names-container">
        <input type="text" id="player1" placeholder="Player 1 Name">
        <input type="text" id="player2" placeholder="Player 2 Name">
    </div>
    <div class="buttonsContainer">
        <button class="startBtn" id="start" class="name-field">Start</button>
        <button class="resetBtn" id="reset" class="name-field">Reset</button>
    </div>
    <div class="message"></div>
    <div class="resultsContainer"></div>
</div>
```